# Sending Outlook Email Using Excel VBA generates error: user-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to send email from Excel 2010 via Outlook.

Outlook is open and I have selected the reference to Outlook 14.0

I created a macro called SendEmail:

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.body = mail_body
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

I created another macro called SendMassEmail():

```
Sub SendMassEmail()

    row_number = 1
    Do
    DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
         'MegBox (Sheet.Range("J3"))
          Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "THis is a test  email", Sheet1.Range("J2"))
    Loop Until row_number = 4
   'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

When I run the code it comes up with the following error:

> user-defined type not defined

Comment: What does the editor highlight when the Error occurs? Instead of .CreateItem(olMailItem) just use .CreateItem(0). That works for me.

Comment: Did you add the outlook object library to references? "Tools" -> "References", add "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library". Doing so, made the posted code run like a charm on my machine

Answer (score 0):

As you already checked the *Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library* reference, 
 
you could try late biding like this :

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number>0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Goto 0
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.body = mail_body
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

I changed the `olApp` creation, so that you don't create another instance of Outlook if you already have one running! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code, but you need to add reference to Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library (Tools -> References...):

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.body = mail_body
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

There is another way to do that without importing the library:

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)
    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olMail As Object
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.body = mail_body
    olMail.Send
End Sub
```

I would suggest first solution. Because then you are importing the library it works "better" and you can see a list of properties of the object every time you are working with Outlook objects.